# How to add more dimens.xml files in android?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, size

I have an `LinearLayout` in my `xml` file for my `UI`.

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="170dp"
     android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
          <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/menu_profile_icon" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I specified the `height` of `Layout` in `dp`. My GUI is different in different `emulators` . It is good in `Nexus 5 emulator` but in `Nexus S emulator` it is not correct . My `LinearLayout` is out of the screen in `Nexus S emulator` . What is the solution for it ?

I tried using `sp` also, but no use,

Thank You.

Comment: Just provide a different `dimens.xml` in each of your different `values-xyz` folders

Comment: How many `values-xyz` folders should i create ?
How can it recognize what `dimen.xml` should be executed ?

Comment: How many you need. Android does it for you. Like when you set multiple `drawable-xyz` folders for your graphical elements.

Comment: I haven'y understood your previous comment. By default when i created `project` in `android studio`, two `dimens.xml` files are created. But only one `values folder` is created . Also i don't have any `drawable-xyz` files .

Comment: So... Did you really never read [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The android system will choice the right dimens.xml from the "values" folder according the device characteristics.

Some Characteristics:

1. Screen Density
2. Screen Size
3. Screen Orientation

Example:
 Device A is a HDPI with a LARGE SCREEN.

The folder name should be:

> values-large-hdpi

You have to build the dimens with specific values for each set.

Like the set of Devices with a large screen and XHDPI.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html